# Не запускается Spring приложение

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
        package com.example.Project;
    
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class ProjectApplication {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(ProjectApplication.class, args);
        }
    
    }
     
   

     package com.example.Project.controller;
    
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/users")
    public class Controller {
        @GetMapping("")
        public ResponseEntity getUsers(){
            try {
                return ResponseEntity.ok("Сервер работает!");
            }
            catch ( Exception e){
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Произошла ошибка!");
            }
        }
    }
```

pom.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>Project</name>
        <description>CRM System</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>19</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
    
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.8</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-docs</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <backend>html</backend>
                                <doctype>book</doctype>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

А в Run выкидывает вот это

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.0)

2022-12-09T09:33:46.461+07:00  INFO 37636 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.Project.ProjectApplication   : Starting ProjectApplication using Java 19 with PID 37636 (C:\Users\Z\Desktop\project\target\classes started by Z in C:\Users\Z\Desktop\project)
2022-12-09T09:33:46.466+07:00  INFO 37636 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.Project.ProjectApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-12-09T09:33:46.603+07:00  INFO 37636 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-12-09T09:33:46.603+07:00  INFO 37636 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-12-09T09:33:47.667+07:00  INFO 37636 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2022-12-09T09:33:47.669+07:00  INFO 37636 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-12-09T09:33:47.702+07:00  INFO 37636 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 25 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2022-12-09T09:33:47.717+07:00  INFO 37636 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2022-12-09T09:33:47.718+07:00  INFO 37636 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-12-09T09:33:47.733+07:00  INFO 37636 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-12-09T09:33:48.960+07:00  INFO 37636 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-12-09T09:33:48.978+07:00  INFO 37636 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-12-09T09:33:48.978+07:00  INFO 37636 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.1]
2022-12-09T09:33:49.081+07:00  INFO 37636 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-12-09T09:33:49.084+07:00  INFO 37636 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2477 ms
2022-12-09T09:33:49.217+07:00  WARN 37636 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2022-12-09T09:33:49.224+07:00  INFO 37636 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-12-09T09:33:49.268+07:00  INFO 37636 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-12-09T09:33:49.314+07:00 ERROR 37636 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: по-видимому какие-то проблемы с подключением к БД. У вас есть файл application.properties или application.yml? Где ваша конфигурация?

Comment: И приложите класс конфигурация дата сурса, если он у вас есть конечно

Answer (score 0):

В описании к проблеме сказано что источник данных настроить не удалось, потому что вы не указали url.

Откройте папку resources, если вы используете application.yaml, то ваша конфигурация выглядит так:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

Если у вас application.properties, то его содержимое выглядит так:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres
spring.datasource.user = postgres
spring.datasource.password = postgres
spring.datasource.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
```